# Limiting length(div width) of an <a> element division

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

Is there a way to limit the width of an "a" element? I'm using "a" elements as toggle buttons, but the blank space to the right of the "a" element remains of the pointer cursor style, which I do not want. Here's some code:

HTML:

```
<a class="ChartLink" id="CapstoneLink"> Global Leadership </a>
```

CSS:

```
.ChartLink, a {
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer; }
```

All of the white space to the left of the text remains of the pointer cursor. How do I limit the length of the text to just the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you commented, I guess what you need is `margin` and not `padding`, because `padding` is counted inside the element whereas `margin` is counted outside. Learn [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) and you will get the concept.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Trg7c/3/)

```
.ChartLink, a {
   margin: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

Well, your question explains something different, and your provided markup is different so I assume that you are nesting `div` element inside `a` as if it's just `a` than the white space won't be there as it's an `inline` element by default.. And since `div` is a `block` level element by default you need to make it `inline`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Trg7c/)

```
a.ChartLink div {
    display: inline;
}
```

<s>[What you are doing](http://jsfiddle.net/Trg7c/1/)</s>

[What you want to](http://jsfiddle.net/Trg7c/2/)

---

Though we are making `div` element `inline` here, it would be more preferable to use `span` instead.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. :) Removed my comment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's actually the other way around. I have multiple <a> elements inside of a div, and the white space after the <a> elements still carries the pointer.

Comment: @Tim can you create a fiddle

Comment: @Tim Edited my answer, you can check

Comment: @Mr.Alien Found the error as I was creating the fiddle. Because of my '.ChartLink, a' css call, the pointer was being applied to the '.ChartLink class divs, which made the entire div(including the white space) use the pointer. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/2xrRr/) something similar to my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tim Your selector is wrong there, writing `.class, a` will select all the `a` elements in your document :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien You're right, I meant to select all the 'a' elements inside the '.ChartLink' class divs, instead of selecting all 'a' elements and all '.ChartLink' elements, which is where it went wrong.